# Integral involving $\coth (x)$: Maple and Mathematica disagree

Tags: integration

I was posed an interesting integral.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\coth(x)}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{3x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)dx .$$

The integral evaluates to $\displaystyle\frac{-2}{{\pi}^{2}}\zeta(3)$ (Mathematica confirms this), but for some reason Maple says it is divergent (gives infinity).

Is there a way to evaluate this using real analysis?  I have seen a nice complex analysis solution resulting in the aforementioned zeta solution.

I looked at the Taylor series for $\dfrac{\coth(x)}{x^{3}}$ and it is :

$$ \frac{1}{x^{4}}+\frac{1}{3x^{2}}-\frac{1}{45}+\frac{2x^{2}}{945}-\frac{x^{4}}{4725}+\cdots $$

It would appear the first two terms have been subtracted from both sides and made part of the integrand. Yet, upon integrating the Taylor series, it appears divergent.

$$\int\left(\frac{\coth(x)}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{3x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)=-\frac{x}{45} + \frac{2x^{3}}{2035}-\frac{x^{5}}{23625}+\frac{2x^{7}}{654885}+\cdots$$

Any ideas on a good method to evaluate this? Series? Double integrals? etc.

I just pointed out the Taylor series because I found it interesting. Often times, Taylor series will converge to a result, but here it does not appear to. I suppose I am overlooking something.

Comment: I still want to see your solution with zeta functions!

Comment: I wouldn't call what you've written a *Taylor series* for that function. I'd say it doesn't have a Taylor series around zero.

Comment: Maybe Mapple calculates it by splitting into 2 or 3 integrals...

Comment: I had also a similar problem to yours and [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Mar/msg00898.html)

Comment: Maple 15 does not say the integral diverges, it merely fails to evaluate it.

Comment: Maple 10 actually gave me infinity. The Taylor series for coth(x) has a is ill-defined at 0 because the first term is 1/x. Thanks everyone for your input. It is always valued.

Comment: The expansion would be called the Laurent Series around $0$.  This is just a name, everyone knows what was meant here.  Saying "the series expansion around $0$" also makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First recall that $\coth(x)=i\cot(ix).$  Since $$\pi\cot(\pi x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2x}{x^{2}-n^{2}},$$ we have that $$\pi\coth(\pi x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2x}{x^{2}+n^{2}}.$$ Rearrange and let $u=\pi x.$ Then $$\frac{\coth(u)}{u^{3}}=\frac{1}{u^{4}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{u^{2}\left(u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{u^{4}}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^{2}n^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{u^{2}}+\frac{-1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right).$$  Splitting up the sum  this is $$\frac{1}{u^{4}}+\frac{2}{u^{2}\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{2}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{u^{4}}+\frac{1}{3u^{2}}-\frac{2}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right).$$  Here we used the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}.$ This last series converges absolutely, which explains why substracting off the $\frac{1}{u^{4}}$  and $\frac{1}{3u^{2}}$  is so important. (the Taylor series tells us this as well)  This also means we can rearrange things freely.  Thus our integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{2}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)du=\frac{-2}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}du.$$  Substituting $u=n\pi x$  we see that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}du=\frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}du=\frac{1}{n}$$ where we note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\pi$. This gives us the final answer of  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\coth(u)}{u^{3}}-\frac{1}{3u^{2}}-\frac{1}{u^{4}}\right)du=\frac{-2}{\pi^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}=\frac{-2\zeta(3)}{\pi^{2}}.$$

I hope that helps,

**Remark:**  Consider $\frac{\coth\left(u\right)}{u^{2m-1}}$ for integers $m$.  Let $$\left[\frac{\coth\left(u\right)}{u^{2m-1}}\right]$$ refer to the same series, except that we cut off the terms in the Laurent expansion around zero where the power is negative.  Then it is possible to prove a generalization that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\coth\left(u\right)}{u^{2m-1}}\right]=(-1)^{m+1}\frac{2\zeta(2m-1)}{\pi^{2m-2}}.$$  This can be proven using the ideas above.

**Zeta function:**  There is some connection between your integral and $\zeta^'(-2).$  In a similar way the integral of $\left[\frac{\cosh(x)}{x^{2m-1}}\right]$ is connected to $\zeta^'(-2m+2)$. I have some ideas, but cannot pin it down exactly the way I want. Just note in particular that $$\zeta^'(-2)=-4\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}.$$

Comment: Aw man. My first thought when reading the question was "I wish I could use that cotangent identity." Then I read the first line of your answer and slap myself.

Comment: @anon: Haha, that comment made me laugh, I know that feeling!  I am still trying to think of how to use something like $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$ and partial integration.  I mean we have $$\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2}}{e^x-1}dx,$$  Things look like they are almost there, and we can write $$\coth(x)=1+\frac{2}{e^{2x}-1},$$ which looks good too.  Just not quite there though...

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

In Maple 15 I get:

> int(coth(x)/x^3 - 1/3/x^2 - 1/x^4, x = -infinity .. infinity);

$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {\coth \left( x \right) }{{x}^{3}}}
-1/3\,{x}^{-2}-{x}^{-4}{dx}$

So Maple doesn't know how to do this symbolically.  Try it numerically:

> evalf(%);

-.2435876565

Now can Maple guess what that number is?

> identify(%);

$-2\,{\frac {\zeta  \left( 3 \right) }{{\pi }^{2}}}$

Comment: I have Maple 10. An older version may be the reason. I entered the integral in just as you have and it gave infinity.

Comment: I was looking at this and got to thinking there should be a way to do this using the Psi function.  Eric's method above kind of resembles the series for Psi.  If we take the series for Psi $\psi(x)=-\gamma + \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x+k-1}\right)$ and differentiate twice, we arrive at  $\psi^{2}(x)=\displaystyle -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(k+x-1)^{3}}$.  Now, letting x=1, gives $\displaystyle-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{k^{3}}=-2\zeta(3)$.  There it is except for dividing by ${\pi}^{2}$. How can we relate this to the integral at hand?.