# Help with $\int_0^\infty {\frac{{\sin t}}{{{e^t} - x}}dt} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\frac{{{x^{n - 1}}}}{{{n^2} + 1}}} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is to show

> $\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin t}}{{{e^t} - x}}dt}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{n - 1}}}}{{{n^2} + 1}}} $ for $-1<x<1$.

The integration is a Lebesgue integration. I have worked on this for half an hour but I still don't know how to solve it except for I can brutally show the Taylor expansion of the left-hand side is consistent with the right-hand side.

Hope someone can help on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The solution method for these kinds of problems is almost always to expand the troublesome part (here $\frac{1}{e^t-x}$) of the integrand in some series and integrating term by term. In some cases (usually if the integrand has a periodic factor) one can split the integration over $[0,\infty)$ into pieces (e.g. $[0,2\pi]$,$[2\pi,4\pi]$,$\ldots$) and then performing some substitution to simplify each integral before solving integral-by-integral.

---

For this problem the former method seems to be the way to go. The term $\frac{1}{e^t-x}$ begs to be expanded in a power-series $e^{-t}\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} e^{-nt}$. This series converges if $|x| e^{-t} < 1$ and since $t\in[0,\infty]$ this is satisfied for all $|x|<1$.

The tricky part is usually to justify interchanging the integration and summation. The conditions that has to be satisfied for this to be allowed is explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) and for this problem we can safely do this if we can prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty |x^{n-1}\sin(t)e^{-nt}|\, {\rm d}t < \infty$$

By using $|\sin(t)| \leq 1$ we get that the integral above is bounded by $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x|^{n-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^{n-1}}{n}=-\frac{\log(1-|x|)}{|x|} < \infty$$ for all $|x|<1$.

---

Finally we need to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t$. This can be done in many ways. If you know contour integration then the integral can be written and evaluated as $\Im \int_0^\infty e^{(i-n)t}\, {\rm d}t = \Im\left(\frac{1}{i-n}\right) = \frac{1}{1+n^2}$.

Another method one can use is integration by parts (two times)

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t = 1 - n\int_0^\infty \cos(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \cos(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t = n\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t$$

which gives $\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-nt}\, {\rm d}t = \frac{1}{1+n^2}$.

---

Putting all pieces togeather gives us the desired result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{e^t-x}\,{\rm d}t = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{1+n^2}$$

for all $|x|<1$. The formula above can also be shown to hold for $x=\pm 1$ where it has closed form solutions. For example for $x=1$ the sum evaluates to $\frac{\pi\coth(\pi)-1}{2}$, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77326/integral-involving-coth-x-maple-and-mathematica-disagree).

Comment: explaining the exchange of limits is fundamental and commonly overlooked! +1

Answer (score 2):

Factor, 
$$ \frac{\sin t}{e^t - x} = e^{-t} \frac{\sin t}{1 - \frac{x}{e^t}} = e^{-t}\sin t \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{x}{e^t} \right)^n   $$
Now integrate, 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t(n+1)}\sin t ~ dt = \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1} $$ 
Thus, we are left with, 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^2+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2+1} $$

Comment: Like mine.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes like yours, but I posted my answer 15 seconds earlier. I did not know you were answering.

Comment: Now that was funny.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sin t}{e^t-x}=\frac{e^{-t}\sin t}{1-xe^{-t}}=e^{-t}\sin t\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-kt}x^k$$

Then integrate term by term.